# Focusing Element on Stripe not working with Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, tailwind-css

On my React app, I have this piece of code inside a form:

```
<div className="focus:border-orange-400 bg-white border appearance-none border-gray-400"> <CardElement /> </div>
```

Where 'CardElement' is part of [React Stripe Js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react). Everything works as expected but not the "focus:border-orange-400".

As I learned from Stripe documentation, you can also do this:

```
           <CardElement
              options={{
                style: {
                  base: {
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    color: '#424770',
                    '::placeholder': {
                      color: '#aab7c4',
                    },
                  },
                  invalid: {
                    color: '#9e2146',
                  },
                },
              }}
            />
```

But that way, I'm not able to use [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/), like in the first piece of code.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-stripe-js` will render the Stripe elements within an iFrame, meaning that the CSS from Tailwind won't get picked up for the internal element. As you noticed Stripe will give you access to certain [CSS properties](https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style) that you can pass in when creating the element.

You won't be able to use the Tailwind pre-defined CSS variables and class names, but you can look at the Tailwind source and pass those to the Element by using the `:focus` pseudo-element.